# If an analytic function is constant along the imaginary axis, is it constant on it's entire domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

I can't seem to prove this but I also cannot find a counter example.
I am dealing with the idea of a function that is constant on the imaginary axis and is defined through an unbound domain. Is it a constant function?If so, why? And if it isn't, can you show me such function?

I would like to note that this is not a function with ImF being constant, but F is constant when fed imaginary numbers.

Thank aplenty.

Comment: More generally, if an analytic function (on a connected open set in $\mathbb C$)  is constant on a set with a limit point, then it is constant